paying import duty to have a lost phone returned to me
I recently returned from holiday to cuba with a connecting flight from C.D.G Paris and my mobile phone was accidentally left at a security checkpoint. I paid 43 euros for its return and am now being asked for import duty. Is this right?

Probably yes, but in which country? Simplified processing and duty excemptions for travellers' luggage is often limited to items carried across the border in person.

Even if there is no import duty, there may be a charge to prepare and submit the customs documentation. I would contact the courier office and ask about how to deal with it- they have customs folks on-staff if it's a major company like Fedex. If you're being asked to pay 20% VAT on a EUR 2000 phone, especially.

Customs regulations vary by country.  Which country was the phone sent to?

Try to contact your custom, and have it sorted out.
It seems that the sender didn't declare correctly the phone (as return, not just a used phone).
Because you already paid the custom fee, you do not need to pay it again, but custom must know it. So contact them. In may help to find the invoice of the phone, as proof you already paid the duties.
Note: contacting the custom, you should also have an idea on how much such correction would cost, and all "handling fees". I hope less than 40 euros, but ... bureaucracy is bureaucracy.
